# Magento bug : Returning all products in search

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

http://ametrade.dev.icyberking.com

This is my site and i am pulling out my hairs all the day for my search working correctly what is working currently is whatever i search it returns all the products from the site no-matter whats keywords you have used, i have also search through the Google and found that making description and short-description non-searchable could help  in making the result more precise  but this not helped me please share if anyone has any previous experience with situation

I am using magneto 1.7 version.
Thanks.

Comment: Not sure what we are supposed to do about it ...

Comment: wow.. such a big sentence to describe whole problem!

Comment: Is your search index up to date ? This can be a problem.

Your research use LIKE or = ?

Comment: Yup indexes are ready.. i have posted my solution as ans.. anyway thx for comment..

Answer (score 0):

Well after searching more over the google i found solution my problem 
go to file app\code\core\Mage\CatalogSearch\Block\

now search this method setListCollection().

```
public function setListCollection()
{
//        $this->getListBlock()
//           ->setCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
return $this;
}

replace below code

public function setListCollection()
{
$this->getListBlock()
->setCollection($this->_getProductCollection());
return $this;
}
```

Here is the actual solution link....
http://developerview.wordpress.com/2012/08/08/magento-search-not-returning-expected-results/